# Azure Data Factory. Loading data from Source to Target using a control table storing source target and query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having a brain freeze as I cannot remember how to create the following pipeline, and I know it's quite simple.

I know this works as I created something like this previous, but it was nearly 2 years ago, and I've moved jobs so don't remember the method exactly.

I have created a table that has the following data:

| ColumnName | Data |
| --- | --- |
| SourceSchemaName | dim |
| SourceTableName | Table |
| TargetSchemaName | dw |
| TargetTableName | Table |
| ExtractSQL | SELECT Acol1, Acol2 AS Bcol1 FROM dim.Table |
| StoredProc | Load_dimTable |

The query has to have the same column names as the target DB to work,
I remember that bit.

Then I use a look up to get this data from each table that needs the data. The query can also include a parameter if you want to limit this import.

I should be able to use this query to do the copying data from within a foreach. In the copy data, I have the Use Query selected and have `@item().ExtractSQL`, However when I try this I get an error 'Table is required for Copy Activity'.

I was wondering if anyone else had used this method at all. I found it quite useful, now I can't remember how I got it to work. It's so frustrating.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I thought. Though it take me a while to figure it out. But time can be a wonderful thing.

So in the Lookup activity in the query I am selecting the columns of the table above... which looks rubbish, but it looks fine in the preview.

| ColumnName | Data |
| --- | --- |
| SourceSchemaName | dim |
| SourceTableName | Table |
| TargetSchemaName | dw |
| TargetTableName | Table |
| ExtractSQL | SELECT Acol1, Acol2 AS Bcol1 FROM dim.Table |
| StoredProc | Load_dimTable |

Columns

- Source Schema and Table.
- Target Schema and Table.
- SQL example SELECT Acol1, Acol2 AS Bcol1 FROM dim.Table
- Stored Procedure. This copies the data from staging into a 'working' table.

[image: Create a Foreach]

[image: Activities in the Foreach]

My problem was the source wasn't set up correctly.
With the connection. I required two parameters

[image: Set up the parameters]

[image: Set Up Copy Data Source]

Do the same in Sink but use the Targets...

Execute stored procedure use the link service and add the stored procedure name as `@item().LoadSproc`

As long as your control table is set up correctly and the stored procedure is correct. It works fine. I am using a merge in the stored procedure.

Many thanks